# Dask.dataframe.map_partitions with multiple (aligned) DDs

Tags: python, dask

In my current flow, I am required to split up a `dask.bag` into two seperate DFs (because of features require shape-changing manipulation). `df_X` for features and `df_y` for target classification.

I am then calling `dd.map_partitions` to apply a classification algorithm on all partitions in parallel but for that to work I need to merge `df_X` and `df_y` over dask, only to then split them back inside the `dd.map_partitions`.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
labels = mybag.pluck('label').to_dataframe()
features = mybag.pluck('features').map_partitions(some_func).to_dataframe()

features.merge(labels, ...).map_partitions(fit)

def fit(df):
    labels = df['labels']
    features = df['features']
```

I noticed `dask.bag.map_partitons` accepts multiple bags and lets the user apply a function over partitions from multiple bags, handing over responsibility of alignment to the user.

I'm wondering if something similar is achievable and/or desired in `dask.dataframe`.

As a side note, having a callable argument in `dask.bag.to_dataframe` to replace/augment `dask.bag.core.to_dataframe` helper function with something more proprietary will be valuable to me.

Comment: Does `dd.map_partitions` work for you?  It also accepts multiple dataframes as arguments.

Comment: @MRocklin If `dd.map_partitions ` accepts `dask.dataframe`s in either `*args` or `**kwargs` then yes, that's exactly what I need. Documentation doesn't mention that, so I assumed it isn't supported. If it does lmk and I'll try and PR a documentation change.

Comment: Only `*args` I think.  That may still suffice to solve your problem above.